# Python - Compare Column Value To Row Value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Having a bit of a logic issue at the moment... Basically, I'm trying to compare the column values of one CSV to row values in another CSV. Here's my code thus far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

#import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

thresholdsFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select The Thresholds File:')
mDataFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select The M Data File:')

df = pd.read_csv(thresholdsFile)
df2 = pd.read_csv(mDataFile)

def thresholdCheck(thresholds, mdata):
    for index, row in thresholds.iterrows():
        for index1, row1 in mdata.iterrows():
            if (row1[index1]) < row['Minimum Threshold:']:
                print('Minimum threshold broken!')
            elif (row1[index1]) > row['Maximum Threshold:']:
                print('Maximum threshold broken!')
            else:
                print('No threshold broken!')

sampleOutput = thresholdCheck(df, df2)
print(sampleOutput)
```

It produces the following output:

Minimum threshold broken!
Maximum threshold broken!
No threshold broken!
Maximum threshold broken!
None

Which is wrong. :(

Attached are two sample CSVs I put together to test the code.[image: Thresholds] and [image: Machine Data]

So the way it should work is the column values of [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo9Y1.png) Machine Data should be read in vertical fashion and be compared to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5lBX.png) the horizontal rows of the Thresholds Data so in this case it should go like this:

(Oil Temp) 55 is compared to 56 and 115 (min/max thresholds in first picture), triggers being below 56 ---> minimum threshold broken

(Oil Temp) 116 is compared to 56 and 115 (min/max thresholds), triggers above 115 ---> maximum threshold broken

Now

(Oil Press) 43 is compared to 44 and 126 (min/max thresholds), triggers below 44 ---> minimum threshold broken

(Oil Press) 127 is compared to 44 and 126 (min/max thresholds), triggers above 126 ---> maximum threshold broken

**Input**

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Variable Name:':['Oil Temp','Oil Press'],
                    'Minimum Threshold:':[56,44],'Maximum Threshold:':[115, 126]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Oil Temp':[95,116],'Oil Press':[43,127]})
```

Comment: can you add in your question the result of `print (df.head(2))` and `print (df2.head(2))` (not the CSVs as pictures). In the meantime, consider changing `row1[index1])` by `row1[row['Variable Name:']])` both times, if I undestand well what you want to do. I have some doubt that `row1[index1])` get what you want. Another advice, doing two loops `for` like this is not the best, especially if your 2 dataframes are big.

Comment: @Ben.T Much appreciated on the reply! I've attached a picture of the sample output. And you hit another relevant point. I'm not hard stuck on the two loops because one of the dataframes is quite larger. If you have a better approach, I'm all ears!

Comment: Haha I miscommunicate what I meant by add the `print` (my english is not always good), I did not mean as a picture but plain text , because it is easier for anybody to use `read_clipboard` or something like that to get the data easily. Anyway I will edit your post shortly. Also, when you say one dataframe is large, I assume you mean `df2`/`mdata`, right?

Comment: @Ben.T You are correct. The machine data file will be larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
## set index, easy to look up
df1 = df1.set_index('Variable Name')

# convert to dict
df2_dict = df2.to_dict(orient='list')

result = []

for k,v in df2_dict.items():
    vals = df1.loc[k].tolist()
    for j in v:

        if j < min(vals):
            result.append('minimum threshold broken')

        if j > max(vals):
            result.append('maximum threshold broken')

print(result)

['minimum threshold broken',
 'maximum threshold broken',
 'minimum threshold broken',
 'maximum threshold broken']
```

**Setup**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Variable Name':['Oil Temp','Oil Press'],
                    'Minimum Threshold': [56, 44],
                    'Maximum Threshold': [115, 126]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Oil Temp':[55, 116],
                    'Oil Press': [43, 127]})
```